# Busy workers from hours ago with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When looking at the Sidekiq admin UI, in the workers tab I see two workers, which started 22 hours ago.

I want to know how can I clear that, because when I do 'Clear workers list' they get cleaned, but when launching another worker, they appear again.

What should I do in order to remove those workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to sidekiq 3.0 which fixes this.